# Css3 hide <li> elements and appear on <li> click

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/EUFrH/

I'm looking to hide the "subline" line from the list and when the "sub" line is clicked it pushes the other lines down to reveal the "subline" li.

Just looking for a way to do it without having to use Js or Jquery

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added the css i have currently

Comment: insted of posting that amount of code please use http://jsfiddle.net/ or something like that to create a demo

Comment: My bad, added the jsfiddle and removed the code

Comment: Check this example http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/css3-image-slide.html similar to your needs.

Comment: This is almost what i want thanks, i'll have a look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make this using the `<input type="checkbox">` or `<input type="radio">`.
The technique is described, for example, here: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/04/css-click-states/

Unfortunately, there seems no way to do that with your current markup.
It is possible to modify the HTML this way:

```
<li class="sub">
  <label for="subline-enabler">
    ... content omitted ...
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="subline-enabler" />
  <ul class="subline">
    <li>
      ... content omitted ...
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/EUFrH/3/

Comment: Thank you, basically there just needs a little styling fiddling :)